Cannot delete files from a swift package in XCode
I've created a new swift package to store all classes from an SDK I'm developing. The idea is to reuse that swift package between other projects.
I've added the package to my current XCode project, by right clicking on the Project Navigator on XCode, and clickin on Add Package Dependencies, next clickin on "Add local..." and finally selecting the empty swift package that I had previously created.
So far so good.
I've then started moving classes form the project to the packge, and when I try to delete a file from the swift pacakge I see that the Delete command is disabled.
Why is so? How should I delete files from the swift package?
Should I be doing somethin different to have it enabled?
Thanks in advance.

You need to open the package itself to delete files. I assume you opened your Xcode project (that has the SPM package as a dependency) and tried to delete files from there?

Thanks @Sweeper. That was it! It is actually quite weird cause I can do almost anything but delete files. Seems kind of counter-intuitive. Anyway, thanks!

Investigating further into that issue. It seems to me that the disabling of the Delete command seems more lik a bug than a feature. I cannot think of nay reason why we should be able to add, edit and move files but not delete them.

It seems like you have opened an Xcode project that has the SPM package as a dependency, and is trying to delete a file in the SPM package from the Xcode project. That is, you are selecting a file in the "Package Dependencies" section.

You should instead open the SPM package itself (File -> Open, then select the Package.swift file). Then you can delete its files. The "root" of the project navigator should be a package icon:


Thanks Sweeper. That was the case. Just let me clarify, that opening the Package.info through File->Open won't work if the project that has the dependency is open (in such case it does not open the package). You need to close the project and then the package can be opened. I do not fully understand why this is needed, though. None of the other development environments I've used in my life require that, and pretending the develpers to work only on the package is not real.
